# Несколько слайдов на одном маркере ( pagination-bullet)

Tags: html, jquery

Каким образом можно реализовать в swiper пролистывание нескольких, например 3-х слайдов по нажатию на один маркер? По-умолчанию к каждому слайдеру создается и привязывается отдельный pagination-bullet.
необходимо привязать к одному такому маркеру произвольное число слайдов.
С помощью CSS получилось реализовать нечто похожее, но при тач-скролле слайды так и пролистываются по одному, а не группой.